# Range validation invalid procedure call

Tags: validation, excel, vba

I have a session, in which I try to put list type validation to a discontinous range. List range comes from another Sheet with name (Range5).

```
With Range("storeRanges").Cells.Validation

Dim ValidationList As Variant
ValidationList = Sheet2.Range("Range5")

   .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:=Join(ValidationList, ",")

End With
```

I get an **"invalid procedure call or argument"** on the **.add line**. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Join only works on 1D arrays. A Range value assigned to a variant is always 2D. If the range is a column, transpose it; if a row, transpose twice.

Comment: Yeah, figured out in the meanwhile. Solved with: `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _ Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=Range5"`
And I put `.Delete` before `.Add`.

Comment: Please don't write `[SOLVED]` in the title... Instead, post your answer as an answer (not a comment) and then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo, the solution is:

```
With Range("storeRanges").Cells.Validation

Dim ValidationList As Variant
ValidationList = Sheet2.Range("Range5")

.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=Range5"

End With
```

Notice the `.Delete` and the `Formula1:="=Range5"`.